# Page number and chapter name in the header - memoir package

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm looking through the memoir manual, and I'm having trouble finding the appropriate command - how do I set up page numbering and having it print the chapter name (both in a header)?

Something like:

```
1          Foo Ducks      |      Foo Ducks          2
   I say something and    |    then it's continued
```

where `|` is the middle of the book and to the left and right are the pages. Obviously the spacing here isn't perfect, but I hope it gives the general idea. (Note: I'd like to use the default options for `\documentclass{memoir}`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
\createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo ducks}
\kant

\end{document}
```

For those interested this article might be useful: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/